# Angular - ngAnimate - Animate.css - Item first shows and then the animation starts

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate, animate.css

I have a problem with Angular - ngAnimate - Animate.css combination (using ngAnimate as a separate module, not the old version).

So I have a list which is actually a table and each tr is repeat with ng-repeat.
The list can be modified, it's a guests list, and I have a button which just adds a new object (guest) to the model that is displayed with the same ng-repeat. For each  that is added to the list, I use this CSS rule to make it fade In to the list:

```
#ic-booking-details .ic-confirmed-guest-list tr.ng-enter {
   -webkit-animation: slideInLeft 0.5s;
   animation: slideInLeft 0.5s;
}
```

The animation is shown, but the problem is it first shows in the list, fully visible for a really short period (about 100ms), and then it starts animating -> it hides and then starts to fade in. Ofcourse, it shouldn't show first, and then fade In, it should fade In while not visible at all.

Am I missing a CSS rule for this to work properly? Right now I'm using only ng-enter.

Thanks!

EDIT: this is the HTML which repeats the guests:

```
<div  class="ic-confirmed-guest-list-holder">
   <table class="ic-confirmed-guest-list">
       <tr ng-repeat="(k,v) in guests.data">
           <td class="ic-guest-number">
                        <span ng-class="{error: ui.guests.errors[k].hasError}" ng-click="guests.swap(k)">Guest #{{k+1}}</span>
                        <span ng-hide="guests.selected != k" class="ic-current-guest"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td ng-click="guests.swap(k)" class="ic-guest-full-name">{{v.firstName}}
                        {{v.lastName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span ng-hide="k==0" ng-click="removeGuest(k)" class="ic-remove-icon"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have additional CSS to hide and show based on classes that $animate uses:

```
.ng-enter,
.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity:0;
 }

.ng-leave,
.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
     opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: I love you  man :) I didn't see that an additional CSS has to be included, is it somewhere in the docs ?

Comment: There is some documentation on the angular site: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate. Although, there are probably better tutorials out there:http://www.nganimate.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem has nothing to do with the animation, but is related to the time period before angular starts to update the page.

You should add ng-cloak to the elements.  (I can not see the html.)

```
<div ng-cloak>
..list here..
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to put it on the table and tr tags but no success, will try to experiment with that a little more!